# Determine if 3d point inside sphere

Tags: python, python-2.7, 3d

In python I am trying to write a function to determine if a x, y, z (floating point) position is within a sphere.

My mathematical understanding is that the function below should give me correct answer, but the test call returns outside sphere but I believe it shouldn’t be.

```
def IsWithinSphere(x, y, z, radius):
    c = (pow(x, 2) + pow(y, 2) + pow(z, 2)) <= pow(radius, 2)
    print 'c = %d' %c

IsWithinSphere(30.8, 69, 69, 100)
```

Response from function: c = 0 (outside)

Comment: The calculation is correct. The point _is_ outside the sphere.

Comment: The distance of that point from the origin is ~ 102.32614524157547

Comment: something I learned with QA: first test (don't believe) the test itself!

Answer (score 2):

I believe your code is correct. (30.8^2 + 69^2 + 69^2)^0.5 = 102 (3 s.f.). This is more than your radius of 100 so it's outside of the sphere.